# is it possible to dispatch an action to multiple browsers in redux?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I am new to redux/redux saga and I am trying to develop an app where I have two browsers interacting with each other via redux saga actions. Currently, I am able to dispatch actions within the same browser, but if I want to dispatch an action to the other browser, the app does not appear to be responding to the dispatched actions. I'm pretty much using the tutorial on https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html for my code.

Before I share my code I want to understand if it is possible to dispatch an action using redux to another user on a different browser. If so, can someone please help me understand how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* establish a `websocket` connection to your server and subscribe to actions to dispatch on each browsers `redux` store (Publish-Subscribe).

Its not an easy task though. You will have to make sure the actions are dispatched in the exact same order in each browser, to make sure to keep the states synchronized.

Downside is, in order to maintain order, you will have to wait for your server to process your actions, and have no immediate visual feedback (or at least delayed by networking). So you will probably end up with two separate stores, or have to handle that delay somehow visually.

Comment: What if I just wanted one redux store to only one other store

Comment: If only one is dispatching and the other one is read-only that could simplify things, but only the fact that there are only 2 instead of n does not simplify much really, since browsers cannot make P2P connections.